# Operator '<>' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and string ""

Tags: database, vb.net

while using the given below code showing one error. The error is : `Operator '<>' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and string "".`  Help me to find a proper solution. Thank You.

Code:

```
 If sdr1.Read Then
   If sdr1(1) <> "" Then
     NameLabel.Text = sdr1(0).ToString + " " + sdr1(1).ToString + " " + sdr1(2).ToString
   Else
     NameLabel.Text = sdr1(0).ToString + " " + sdr1(2).ToString
   End If
     dept_id.Text = sdr1(3)
 End If
   sdr1.Close()
```

Comment: In VB `&` is the string concatenation operator, not `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column contains a null value.  You have to check for nullness before trying to do other comparisons.

So...

```
If DBNull.Value Is sdr1(1) Then
    '  Got a null value from the database.
End If
```

If you don't care about whether the value is null, or empty - just want to treat them the same...

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(sdr1(1)) Then
    '  The value is either null or empty.
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check whether the data you are comparing is NULL or not before you use it inside any operation:

```
If sdr1.Read Then
   If Not IsDbNull(sdr1(1)) Then
     If sdr1(1) <> "" Then
       NameLabel.Text = sdr1(0).ToString + " " + sdr1(1).ToString + " " + sdr1(2).ToString
     Else
       NameLabel.Text = sdr1(0).ToString + " " + sdr1(2).ToString
     End If
    End If
    dept_id.Text = sdr1(3)
End If
   sdr1.Close()
```

or you can simply use

```
If sdr1.Read Then
   If Not IsDbNull(sdr1(1)) Then
       NameLabel.Text = sdr1(0).ToString + " " + sdr1(1).ToString + " " + sdr1(2).ToString
   Else
       NameLabel.Text = sdr1(0).ToString + " " + sdr1(2).ToString
   End If
   dept_id.Text = sdr1(3)
End If
sdr1.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `If sdr1(1) IsNot "" Then` or   `If Not IsDBNull(sdr1(1))` Then instead for `<>` that will give you better result

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.IsNullorEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead for checking the same

Ex:-

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(x) Then
  'Do Something
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Use instead of If function

```
try
If sdr1.Read Then
   If Not IsDbNull(sdr1(1)) Then
       NameLabel.Text = sdr1(0).ToString + " " + sdr1(1).ToString + " " + sdr1(2).ToString
   Else
       NameLabel.Text = sdr1(0).ToString + " " + sdr1(2).ToString
   End If
   dept_id.Text = sdr1(3)
End If
Catch ex As Exception

end try
```